# Rails corrupting binary field default value on schema load

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

This entry in my schema.rb:

```
create_table "my_settings", id: :integer, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
  t.string "IMEI", limit: 25, null: false
  t.binary "enabled", limit: 1, default: "b'0'", null: false
  t.integer "output_channel", default: 1, null: false
  t.binary "inverse_relay", limit: 1, default: "b'0'", null: false
  t.integer "message_syntax", default: 0, null: false
end
```

is producing the following SQL and error message during `rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test`, which renders my test suite unusable:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Invalid default value for 'enabled': CREATE TABLE `my_settings` 
(`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`IMEI` varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
`enabled` varbinary(1) DEFAULT x'62273027' NOT NULL, 
`output_channel` int DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, 
`inverse_relay` varbinary(1) DEFAULT x'62273027' NOT NULL, 
`message_syntax` int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As you can see, the default values for the binary fields don't match. Any idea why rails is mangling these values? My schema.rb file is UTF-8 encoded in case that's relevant. I'm using rails 5.1 with MYSQL 5.7.15 hosted on my Macbook for my test suite.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: as requested, the SHOW CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMEI` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `output_channel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `inverse_relay` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `message_syntax` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5140 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Those defaults don't match. Why does `b'0'` become `x'62273027'`?

Comment: I have no idea, this is what I'm asking... If that wasn't clear I'll edit the question.

Comment: Why is your original default `b'0'`? The hex versions is a direct conversion of that string, byte for byte. The default notation is `false`.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite sure; this schema file hasn't been produced by successive migrations, but by `rails db:schema:dump`. This makes it more bewildering to me that Rails doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: It's like some default in your MySQL side of things has caused the schema dumper to become very confused and this confusion is increasing as it re-interprets the schema the second time.

Comment: So b'0' is the MYSQL bit value literal that represents false, and is the default value from the db. (The db is shared amongst several services, and this table was probably created by hand by someone working on a Node app; nevertheless, my rails app needs to be able to access it.)

Comment: The `b'...'` notation is used by MySQL but the Rails schema subsystem seems unable to deal with it, so if there's a way of getting that dump to be emitted with the usual `false` value you'd be on the right track. Otherwise this could be a bug in MySQL. Can you edit your question to include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the affected table?

Comment: Done, thanks for taking an interest btw.

Comment: Why are those `BIT` type columns? This is getting really strange. I'm used to Rails creating `TINYINT(1)` for boolean values. If you scratch rebuild from your migrations do you get the same outcome?

Comment: This table was created by hand in MYSQL by someone writing a microservice in Node, who presumably thought a bit flag was a space -efficient way to store a Boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails likes to represent boolean columns as `TINYINT(1)` instead of bit or boolean columns, at least when it comes to MySQL. The presence of a `BIT(1)` field in the original schema is confusing the schema dumper, it's expressing the default as a binary string `b'0'`.

While that string's valid to MySQL, the Rails schema interpreter thinks that's a string of some sort, so when it composes a migration to create the temporary version of that table it comes out mangled as `x'62273027'` which is just the hex version of the literal string `b'0'`, where `62` is `b` and so on.

The way to fix this is to either force switch the original column to `TINYINT(1)` and make it conform to the expectations of the Ruby schema dumper, or to dump in SQL format:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Where that makes a `.sql` dump file instead of a `.rb` one. This can better deal with schemas that the dumper can't understand.

Comment: So Rails explodes at the sight of the only real primitive in computer science? Good to know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not exactly. It's just that MySQL's representation of that is irregular, it's not a boolean but a bitfield.